# Angular bootstrap tabs don't work with ui-iconpicker

Tags: angularjs, tabs, icons, picker

I'm trying to implement [Angular UI Bootstrap Iconpicker](http://justin-lau.github.io/ui-iconpicker/?icon_class=glyphicon%20glyphicon-trash) in my project but it doesn't work because I'm using those js files for angularjs [tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs):

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.0.js"></script>
```

and for ui-iconpicker I use those files:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("bower_components/ui-iconpicker/dist/scripts/ui-iconpicker.min.js")"></script>
```

I think there is a confusion between the two files (ui-bootstrap-tpls) but when I remove one of them the associated component don't work!! any help please

Comment: Why don't you use the same file and reference it in one place?

Comment: I tried to use only the second one but my tabs don't display correctly the same thing for the iconpicker when I use the first file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is known to the author of ui-iconpicker.

See [ui-iconpicker Issue #4: Doesn't work with ui-bootstrap >= 0.11.0](https://github.com/justin-lau/ui-iconpicker/issues/4)

[@justin-lau](https://github.com/justin-lau) justin-lau added the `wontfix` label on Jan 29, 2015

> [@rapheki](https://github.com/rapheki) commented on May 20:
>
> i had a similar issue, you need to modifiy the `ui-iconpicker.js` file and replace in line 156 (the `templates/iconpicker.html`):
>
> - "dropdown>" to "uib-dropdown>"
> - "dropdown-toggle>" to "uib-dropdown-toggle>"

Comment: Your answer didn't work for me but you brought me closer to the solution that I found here https://github.com/justin-lau/ui-iconpicker/issues/3 thank you for your reply